# Adding custom Typescript type declaration for a node module in Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am struggling to add a type declaration for `react-load-script` within a Create React App application.

Within the `src` folder, I created a `react-load-script.d.ts` file and added the following:

```
// Type definitions for React Load Script

declare module 'react-load-script' {
  import * as React from 'react'
  interface Script {
    url: string
  }
}
```

With the above I am getting the error:

> JSX element type 'Script' does not have any construct or call
>   signatures.

Where am I going wrong? This is the module: https://github.com/blueberryapps/react-load-script

This is my current use of it within the app:

```
<Script url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?                               key=your_api_key&libraries=places"          
    />
```

I also need to add types for the onLoad:

```
<Script url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?                               key=your_api_key&libraries=places"          
      onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad}        
    />
```

Thanks so much.

**Update from comments**

I moved and renamed the declaration file to `/@types/react-load-script/index.d.ts`

In `tsconfig.json` I added the following to `compilerOptions`:

`"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]`

This is the `index.d.ts` entire contents:

```
// Type definitions for React Load Script
import React from 'react'

export interface ScriptProps {
  url: string
  onLoad: () => void
  // etc...
}

export default class Script extends React.Component<ScriptProps> {}
```

With this I am still getting the error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-load-script'.
>   '/Users/sb/git/fl-app/node_modules/react-load-script/lib/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `Script` is the component, but your interface define its `props`.

Following the lib [sources](https://github.com/blueberryapps/react-load-script/blob/master/src/index.jsx), you may have to do:

```js
export interface ScriptProps {
  url: string;
  onLoad: () => void;
  // etc...
}

export default class Script extends React.Component<ScriptProps> {}
```

---

**Edit after comments**

Your types concerns a third-party *module*. You have to advise Typescript about it. For that you'll encapsulate your types in a module declaration, like that:

```js
// index.d.ts
declare module 'react-load-script' {
  // imports here...

  export interface ScriptProps {
    url: string;
    onLoad: () => void;
    // etc...
  }

  export default class Script extends React.Component<ScriptProps> {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. However this gives me: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-load-script'.`. This is the entire code of my declaration file, incase I have done something wrong: https://pastebin.com/ysAY8hWF

Comment: You should say to typescript compiler where to find your types definition files. In your `tsconfig.json` define `typeRoots` with your types folder AND `node_modules/@types`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I edited the main post with details, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks so much Richard... will give it a go. When you put `// imports here...` what imports do they refer to?

Comment: Hmm.. in your case I think about `React`, but it may be not necessary I don't remember if you have to do it or not. I will test it later in the day.

Answer (score 6):

Note: create a folder called 'custom-types' in the root directory of your project and inside it create the file 'index.d.ts'

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module 'your-module-that-has-no-types';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...other props,
    "typeRoots": ["./custom-types", "node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "custom-types/index.d.ts"  ],
}
```